# Text height is being squashed Win Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have been working on a drupal website, so there are plenty of layers of div and CSS.

My problem is appearing in chrome/windows (NOT win/ff ubuntu/ff/chrome mac/ff/safari) were the text height is being swashed.

my CSS Contains:

```
@font-face {font-family: myFirstFont; src: url(TrajanPro-Bold.otf); font-weight:bold;}
#site-name {font-size:26px; padding:60px 10px 5px 0; float: left; font-family:myFirstFont;}
```

There is a reference to line-height in the body text but this doesn't seem to affect the look of the text.

Is this just a bug or is there a way in HTML5 to set Text Height?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It is difficult to find the problem without looking into it, you should put it on fiddle, or you can try line-height first may be issue is with line-height.

Comment: Does this happen in safari on windows?  Both Chrome and Safari use Webkit as a layout engine, so you might be able to tell if it is a windows problem/chrome bug or if it is an issue with your styles.